# Issue with testing React component in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine

I am new to a React project and am getting some failures running the test suite ('gulp spec-app'). Basically, there is a component of the app where you add a new patient and then there are a few dropdown menus for demographic info. If I test manually they work, I can select a gender or race and save the patient, but the Jasmine tests fail. This is the code for the tests:

```
describe('if adding a new patient, ie no patient loaded', () => {
    let patient;

    beforeEach(() => {
      patient = {mrn: "", surgeries: [], diagnoses: []};

      render(PatientPage, {patient, schema});
    });

    it('renders patient race as empty initially', () => {
      expect('.race-select .Select-
      placeholder').toContainText('Select');
    });

    it('renders race options', () => {
      click('.race-select .Select-arrow');
      expect('.race-select .Select-menu').toExist();
    });

    it('renders gender options', () => {
      click('.gender-select .Select-arrow');
      expect(`.gender-select .Select-
        option:contains(${currentGender})`).toExist();
      expect(`.gender-select .Select-
        option:contains(${newGender})`).toExist();
    });
```

The first 'it' passes but the other two do not. The error output for the first failing test is:

`Expected .race-select .Select-menu to exist`

and the other two failures similarly say:

`Expected .gender-select .Select-option:contains(M) to exist 
Expected .gender-select .Select-option:contains(F) to exist`

First time posting here so please let me know if there is some other context clue I left out.